# Spring mvc. Unable to render parameter

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm pretty new in spring mvc and I'm trying to write simple helloworld with jsp by different chunks of tutorials. Jsp code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
   <body>
      <h1>Hello, ${name}</h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

Controller code:

```
@Controller
public class Main {
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public ModelAndView hello(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "moses") String name) {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("MyView");
    mv.addObject("name", name);
    return mv;
}
}
```

Dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.stax.controllers"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

When I'm typing ${na in jsp my Idea sees this parameter so I assume that I do it correct. And when I run this app, everything works except that parameters passed to jsp are not rendered. And instead of "Hello, Moses" I receive "Hello, ${name}". What am I doing wrong? If you need some more details, please, tell me.
Also my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.stax</groupId>
<artifactId>site</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>site Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>site</finalName>
</build>
```

web.xml:

```
  <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee

 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Try adding these dependencies to Maven and let me know: `<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
 </dependency>

Comment: Also make sure that in web.xml your version is 2.5 or 3.0

Comment: As an aside, I recommend looking at Thymeleaf as an alternative to JSP. I'm not really familiar with JSP, so I'm not sure what the issue is, but this is a well-asked question.

Comment: Actually, have you set a breakpoint in the controller and confirmed that the parameter is being set correctly by the dispatcher?

Comment: Could you also post the web.xml. It contains valuable info

Comment: @geoand thanx a lot. Problem was in some old web.xml definition. Now it works.

Comment: Ok I will add it as an answer for future readers to see easily

Comment: @geoand I will also add my old web.xml and accept your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify version 2.5 or version 3.0 in web.xml for EL to be activated by default.

As recommended by @chrylis you should checkout [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/) if you are starting a new project. 
It's a huge improvement over JSP.

Another suggestion would be to check out [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) since it vastly simplifies the Spring configuration.